# Automatically replace the folder icon with the icon of the exe-file inside the folder

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory, desktop.ini

I wrote a batch file which looks through all the subdirectories of a directory, then copies the basename of the `.exe` file from each subdirectory, creates a `desktop.ini` file inside that subdirectory, and inserts the relative filename into it, (as the IconResource).

The problem is that the `desktop.ini` is created correctly, but only in one subdirectory. I need it to be created in all subdirectories of the initial directory, which should be the parent of the running batch file.

```bash
@echo off

for /d %%D in (*) do (
  set "exefile="
  for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%%D\*.exe"') do (
    set "exefile=%%F"
    set "foldpath=%%D"
    goto :next
  )
  :next
  if defined exefile (
    echo [.ShellClassInfo]>>"%foldpath%\desktop.ini"
    echo ConfirmFileOp=0 >>"%foldpath%\desktop.ini"
    echo IconResource=.\%exefile%>>"%foldpath%\desktop.ini"
    echo IconIndex=0 >>"%foldpath%\desktop.ini"
    attrib +s +h "%foldpath%\desktop.ini"
  )
)
```

This is the entry in desktop.ini:

```ini
[.ShellClassInfo]
ConfirmFileOp=0 
IconResource=.\AltTabTer.exe
IconIndex=0
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgNk3.png).

Comment: Replace everything from second command line to the `if` condition by `for /D %%I in (*) do set "exefile=" & for %%J in ("%%I\*.exe") do if not defined exefile (` which is the second line after `@echo off`. The other lines are: __3.__ `set "exefile=1"` __4.__ `(echo [.ShellClassInfo]` __5.__ `echo ConfirmFileOp=0` __6.__ `echo IconResource=.\%%~nxJ` __7.__ `echo IconIndex=0` __8.__ `) >"%%I\desktop.ini"` __9.__ `%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +s +h "%%I\desktop.ini"` and __10.__ `)`. Then the code works as it should without the usage of delayed variable expansion and labels.

Comment: It is additionally also better than your code as it opens the file `desktop.ini` only once, writes all lines into the file without a trailing space in comparison to your code as long as there are no trailing spaces in the batch file, and finally closes `desktop.ini` instead of opening `desktop.ini`, writing first line, close it, opening it again, seeking to end, appending a line, closing it, opening it again and so on. Further `cmd.exe` has not to search in file system on each folder with an executable for `atttrib` because of being specified with fully qualified file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /D %%I in (*) do set "exefile=" & for %%J in ("%%I\*.exe") do if not defined exefile (
    set "exefile=1"
    (echo [.ShellClassInfo]
     echo ConfirmFileOp=0
     echo IconResource=.\%%~nxJ
     echo IconIndex=0
    ) >"%%I\desktop.ini"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +s +h "%%I\desktop.ini"
)
```

### How it works

[Executing a batch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3GAg.gif)